# Bypass proxy for everything but local addresses?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, proxy

I know this is a bit unconventional, but I want to bypass the proxy for **all external addresses/domains** and only proxy internal addresses. How would I craft a proxy bypass setting string that meets the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

By using [Hotspot Shield](http://www.appbrain.com/app/hotspot-shield-vpn-for-android/hotspotshield.android.vpn) you can bypass proxy installed on any network

Comment: @Raman I don't want to completely bypass the proxy for all connections. I want to bypass the proxy for all external addresses. In other words I only want to proxy addresses in my local subnet.